# Account entity and More address entity in MS CRM 2011

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

My need is selecting addresses from ''More Address'' entity, that linked to Account entity, based on condition. Because most of accounts have more than one address.
I'm planning to add a pick list to account entity and after that when user selects ''Address 1'' from picklist all address fields should fill from ''More address'' entity which named ''Address 1''. If user selects ''Address 2'' the same should be occur.

More Address entity:
Address 1
Address 2
Address 3

Can u give me an idea ?
Thanks.

image links below:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlC2X.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YF2UM.jpg

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot or something so that your problem can be better understood.

Comment: @JatinBansal img links added.

Comment: have you tried creating a work-flow for this task of yours?

Comment: Are you trying to use the CustomerAddress entity? You know how that works right, address1 and address2 are saved on the Account entity as address1_line1 and address2_line1 for example, then a N:N carries on with the relationship in the CustomerAddress entity. For address1 and address2 you can use the account entity but anything afterwards you'll have to be more creative with your Jscripting populating the addres fields ...